# Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. Digital Ocean - AppPlatform

Tags: docker, .net-core, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy a .NET Core 6.0 project to Digital Ocean using Apps Platform. But time and time again I am getting this exception:

Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.

I've tried a lot of things and variations so far. Other resolutions to this exception suggest to run these commands on local machine:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

But as this is deployment to app platform, I think that these won't work. I've even tried sneaking in `dotnet dev-certs https` command in Dockerfile but the same exception occurs.

Here's what I've built so far:

- Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["/Reservations.Api/Reservations.Api.csproj", "Reservations.Api/"]
COPY ["/Reservations.Application/Reservations.Application.csproj", "Reservations.Application/"]
COPY ["/Reservations.Persistance/Reservations.Persistance.csproj", "Reservations.Persistance/"]
COPY ["/Reservations.Security/Reservations.Security.csproj", "Reservations.Security/"]
COPY ["/Reservations.Domain/Reservations.Domain.csproj", "Reservations.Domain/"]
COPY ["/Reservations.UnitTests/Reservations.UnitTests.csproj", "Reservations.UnitTests/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Reservations.Api/Reservations.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "Reservations.Api/Reservations.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /src/build
RUN dotnet dev-certs https

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Reservations.Api/Reservations.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /src/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /src
COPY --from=publish /src/publish .
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+:80;https://+:443;"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Reservations.Api.dll"]
```

- launchsettings.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44641",
      "sslPort": 44366
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Reservations.Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7202;http://localhost:5202",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://+:80;"
      },
      "httpPort": 8080,
      "applicationUrl": "http://+:8080;"
    }
  }
}
```

- In Program.cs
  `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` is included.
- Deployment logs error:

```
[2023-03-01 15:39:53] warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]

[2023-03-01 15:39:53]       No XML encryptor configured. Key {8cbcf317-aff6-4a80-90fa-539eeaf0de94} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.

[2023-03-01 15:39:53] Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.

[2023-03-01 15:39:53] To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.

[2023-03-01 15:39:53] For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlin
```

I am out of ideas, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can upload your pfx certificate on Azure and use it on container : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#load-certificate-in-linuxwindows-containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by removing any resemblance to HTTPS and adapting the app for http-only traffic. Concretely:

```
"Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
=>      "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://+:80;"
      },
      "httpPort": 8080,
      "applicationUrl": "http://+:8080;"
    }
```

In the marked row where I removed s from "https://+:80;", making it into "http://+80;".
Also, I removed `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` from Program.cs.

The point being: App Platforms will handle HTTP security with your app, meaning that you do not need to provide any HTTPS configuration within the app.